# How to restore deleted mail from office 365 using Microsoft graph api

Tags: graph, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I want to restore a mail which we delete using Microsoft graph api.

I don't find any api to restore or recoved a deleted mail using apis.

Comment: Have you tried using the API call (POST /directory/deletedItems/{id}/restore)?

Comment: @Mohan P Did you get any solution?

Comment: @Dev I have tried something this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/deleteditems/messageId/restore. But nothing works getting 400 bad requests.

Comment: Shakthi - Please check the info Glen shared below!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restore method in the Graph API (there also isn't one in MAPI or EWS). When an Item gets deleted in Exchange it just gets moved into another folder in the Mailbox up until the time the retention period of the Item expires then the MFA(Managed Folder Assistant) deletes the Items.

So for example to restore an Item that was in the dumpster you would need to query for the Item in the dumpster like

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@mailbox.com')/MailFolders/recoverableitemsDeletions/messages/
```

Then you could move it back into what ever folder you want using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If you wanted to move it back to the original location it was deleted from you would need to use the LAPFID (Last Active Parent FolderId) property https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2017/06/13/announcing-original-folder-item-recovery/ . Eg to get that on items in the dumpster use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@mailbox.com')/MailFolders/recoverableitemsDeletions/messages/?$select=Subject&$Top=10&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter%3DId%20eq%20'Binary%200x348A')
```

Using the LAPFID is a little tricky as it's only a partial folderId so you need extra code for that, there are a few examples of using it in https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2018/10/using-lapfid-last-active-parent.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. What I needs to pass instead of Binary 0x348A? Is the id of message?

Comment: 0x348A is the extended property that will return the LAPFID value if you want to return it on a particular message include the messageId before any of the query string recoverableitemsDeletions/messages/yourmessageid?querystrings

Comment: Response - {
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('test.iamplus%40outlook.com')/mailFolders('recoverableitemsDeletions')/messages(subject,singleValueExtendedProperties())/$entity",
  "id": "id",
  "singleValueExtendedProperties@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('test.iamplus%40outlook.com')/mailFolders('recoverableitemsDeletions')/messages('id')/singleValueExtendedProperties",
  "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
      "id": "Binary 0x348a",
      "value": "fZMYjZ6rs0+/bUg2z6SblgAAAAABDw=="
    }
  ]
}

Comment: What should I do next from this "singleValueExtendedProperties":[{"id":"Binary 0x348a","value":"fZMYjZ6rs0+/bUg2z6SblgAAAAABDw=="}]? Thanks....

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/gscales/Graph-Powershell-101-Binder/blob/master/Mailbox-Dumpster/Restoring%20a%20Items%20to%20where%20it%20was%20deleted%20from.md will help

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
PS C:\> Get-RecoverableItemsDeletions -Mailbox gscales@datarumble.com -filter "internetMessageId eq '<SIXPR04MB07943FE6A08A363FD78084F3C81B0@SIXPR04MB0794.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com>'" , what will be for Graph request? 
Something like this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter%3D internetMessageId eq <TY2PR02MB342314A873FC59815168C4589B300@TY2PR02MB3423.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com> ? If yes I am not getting any LastActiveParentFolderPath in response.

Comment: You need to pass the singleValueExtendedProperties for the LAPFID to be returned so /MailFolders('RecoverableItemsDeletions')/messages?$filter=internetMessageId%20eq%20'%3CSIXPR04MB07943FE6A08A363FD78084F3C81B0@SIXPR04MB0794.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com%3E'&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20'Binary%200x348A'))