# How to restore trash mails to original folder in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I have tried this [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/deleteditems/{messageId}/restore](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/deleteditems/%7BmessageId%7D/restore) but getting 400 Bad request.

Comment: Please look into this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684575/how-to-restore-deleted-mail-from-office-365-using-microsoft-graph-api).

Answer (score 1):

As Glen said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684575/how-to-restore-deleted-mail-from-office-365-using-microsoft-graph-api) there is no method to directly restore trash mails through Graph API. Please raise a feature request for this in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team could implement it in the future.

Comment: Thanks @shiva I have raised a feature to MS https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41633905-restore-trash-mails-to-original-folder